# Getting vertical position of element in fixed container with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a bit of difficulty when trying to get the vertical position of an element with `scrollTop` when the parent container is `position: fixed`.

When using scrollTop the value output is `0`. I'm guessing this is because the element isn't strictly in the standard flow anymore. Is there anything obvious I'm missing or is there a different way to do this keeping `position: fixed` and without using jQuery. Maybe there is a way to get the position of an element is relation to its parent?

I've attached test code below.

```js
document.getElementById('target').scrollTop;
```

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 1200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}

#element {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="target">
    Target
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to use `offsetTop` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

> The HTMLElement.offsetTop read-only property returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the offsetParent node.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('target').offsetTop);
```

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 1200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}

#element {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="target">
    Target
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Goddamn so simple :( Thanks

Comment: @AdamHughes no problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)?

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

```
document.getElementById('target').getBoundingClientRect().top;
```